# CrystalReportViewer cant connect on ms access database with password/Error on reload

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports, report

Good day sir,

How can I connect my ms access db with password on my crystalreportviewer. I created the crystal report then managed to link the password protected db on the report, but when I ran my program it shows data database log in pop up asking for my password. When I entered the password on my database it still login failed. Please help. thank you
I'eve tried everything i found on the internet but nothing seems to work for me or maybe im searching for the wrong problem.

[image: Login Popup]

**Error happens when I am reloading the Crystal Report**

```
Private Sub frmreportviewer_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Try
        'reportdoc object
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        
        'load report
        cryRpt.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\Report1.rpt")
        
        'parameters definition(if any)
        
        'provide connection info. This is important and you can change it as per your db location
        With crConnectionInfo
            .ServerName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\abc.mdb"
            '.DatabaseName = ""
            '.UserID = ""
            .Password = "password"
        End With

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
        For Each CrTable In CrTables
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
        Next

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I used this code but still asking for login after I refresh it

Comment: Probably should edit question to show vb.net code that establishes connection.

Comment: Im not using any code. I manually created the crystal report and loaded the report by  source.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path to your database file has to be assigned to `crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName`, not to `.ServerName`.